# Find out indices of an array elements

Tags: python, arrays, image-processing

I have this array as a result of subtracting two images after getting there RGB integer values as an arrays

```
arr = img1 - img2

[[[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ..., 
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]
  ..., 
 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ..., 
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]]
```

i used these lines of code to change the shape of array to add the indices of each pixel subtraction

```
x, y, z = arr.shape
indices = np.vstack(np.unravel_index(np.arange(x*y), (y, x))).T
result = np.hstack((arr.reshape(x*y, z), indices))
```

and here what the result looks like:

```
[[  0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   1]
 [  0   0   0   0   2]
 ..., 
 [  0   0   0 511 509]
 [  0   0   0 511 510]
 [  0   0   0 511 511]]
```

the first three values in each row is the RGB difference and the last two values is the X and Y indices
my question here, is there an efficient way to find the indices of the non zero values?

Comment: is my answer what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're saying correctly, you want them per list in your list of lists...

Saying this is your list:

```
l=[[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,0,2],[0,0,0,511,509],[0,0,0,511,510],[0,0,0,511,511]]
```

try running:

```
import numpy as np
ans=[np.nonzero(l[i])[0] for i in range(1,len(l))]
print ans
```

returns:

```
[array([4]), array([4]), array([3, 4]), array([3, 4]), array([3, 4])]
```

So it's an array containing arrays that have the indices of each non-zero element in each list.  Since it uses list comprehension it runs pretty quickly and accession is as simple as using the indices.  It will just be ans[list in list of lists][number of non-zero indices] like so:

```
ans[2][1]
4
```

Comment: If the array is 
l=[[25,5,5,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1],[0,8,0,0,2],[0,0,0,511,509],[0,0,0,511,510],[0,0,0,511,511]]
 i want the result to be the indices (0,0) and (0,2) since the values are non zero, did you understand me ?

Comment: I'm not sure I do, or how that gives you (0,0) and (0,2)

Comment: since the values are non zero i mean 
[25,5,5,0,0] here i have 25 ,5 and 5
[0,8,0,0,2] and for this i have 0,8, and 0 not all three values are zero

Comment: oh so arrays where one of the first three elements are non-zero?

Comment: yup, i couldn't make my words clear enough before
notice that the last two are x, and z indices

Comment: Well you can still use my solution and just check if the number in the arrays is 2 or less because that would mean it is one of the first three elements.

Comment: @semjaavira 
actually the indices that i want not the indices from 0 to 4, the indices are the last two values review the first reply from me to your answer

Comment: I really don't know what you're saying anymore, but if you want non-zero indices, my answer will give you that.  If you want the arrays that contain non-zero indices in the first few indices (however many there are), just write a loop or a if i...in...x statement that checks for whatever bare minimum indices you want to be non-zero.  Understand?   If the first index in that tuple indicates the larger array and the second index indicates that the array in the array has any non-zero 0th through 2nd indices...You can make it output whatever you like, 2s and 1s, or (0,0),(0,2).